# The dragged item is not displayed outside the virtualized list (react-virtuoso, @dnd-kit)

Tags: drag-and-drop, overflow, ui-virtualization, dnd-kit, react-virtuoso

I am trying to use dnd-kit together with react-virtuoso and everything works, except that the dragged item is not displayed outside the virtualized list

How to make the dragged item appear outside the virtualized list? High z-index on the dragged item doesn't work.

And when you start dragging an item inside a virtualized list a horizontal scroll appears, that's not good either.

Sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-kit-board-virtuoso-7yzcwj

Comment: Normally you could add zIndex:
```zIndex: isDragging ? 35 : 20```. (get it from const { isDragging } = useSortable() )
But It is not working when I try on sandbox.

Comment: yeah, becauce overflow-y: auto is set on virtualized list

Comment: Maybe if you can make work around for it you could use zIndex. For now it's the only way I know to do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found a solution.
If you need to display the dragged item outside the virtualized list, you need to use `DragOverlay`

Thanks to @mescalas - https://github.com/mescalas

DragOverlay Docs - https://docs.dndkit.com/api-documentation/draggable/drag-overlay

Updated sandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/dnd-kit-board-virtuoso-7yzcwj